# How to record video with different sound effects on starting and stopping?

Tags: camera, camera-sound

The stock camera app on my Moto G62 5G has a "shutter" sound that is played when I start OR stop recording. The problem is that I'm vision impaired and I'm never sure whether I have just began shooting a video or have just stopped shooting it.

It would be great if I knew a way to play 2 different sounds in the two cases. Any ideas?

I used to use an alternative cam app called HedgeCam 2 which does this. But unfortunately this app has recently become buggy on my device.

Answer (score 0):

This app does it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intermedia.hd.camera.professional

It has many of the same features as HedgeCam 2 too.